# How to take array in one column in a table and set value inside of array of JSON to it in SQL?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table that looks like this but with a lot more data entries

```
Details                             |   Numbers

[{headers: "test", numbers: []}]    |   [1, 2]
[{headers: "test", numbers: []}]    |   [3, 4]
```

I want it to set the numbers inside the JSON to be the Numbers from the numbers columns to look like this:

```
Details                                 |   Numbers

[{headers: "test", numbers: [1, 2]}]    |   [1, 2]
[{headers: "test", numbers: [3, 4]}]    |   [3, 4]
```

Is there an UPDATE script that I can do to set all of my numbers in my JSON to be the values in the numbers column?

Answer (score 0):

You json is not valid.

For your case you can use `JSON_MODIFY` see [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The major point is `JSON_QUERY([Numbers])` else you will get insert a string

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
    ([Details] NVARCHAR(100), [Numbers] varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO tab1
    ([Details], [Numbers])
VALUES
    ('[{"headers": "test", "numbers": []}]', '[1, 2]'),
    ('[{"headers": "test", "numbers": []}]', '[3, 4]')
;
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
UPDATE tab1 
  SET [Details] 
  = JSON_MODIFY([Details],'$[0].numbers',JSON_QUERY([Numbers]))
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM tab1
```

| Details | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| [{"headers": "test", "numbers": [1, 2]}] | [1, 2] |
| [{"headers": "test", "numbers": [3, 4]}] | [3, 4] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/13PT5pfB)